# Given a set of words, how can you identify "n" set of letters that will help you make the maximum number of complete words from the original list?

Tags: string, algorithm, graph

Example:

`n = 9`
`words = {Bike, Tire, Fuel, Biker, Filter, Trike}`
`output = {B,T,I,K,E,F,U,L,R}`

(Order of output is not important. What is important to note is that given a word like FOO, one could not use F,O as the alphabet, but always needed F,O,O. Similar alphabets are treated separately)

What would be the most efficient algorithm to solve this ?
I am thinking along the lines of using the frequency of each character but that does not seem to help much.

Comment: This feels like a variation on the set cover problem, but looking at from another prepective

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov Indeed, this smells NP-complete-ish. I wonder who dares to post an answer without a formal, peer-reviewed proof that he found "the *most efficient solution*" for that one...

Comment: @Marco13 - I have some ideas, and also some examples for difficult cases (like `{am, an, at, ac, awe, ark, owl, wol, low}` where `a` is very popular but useless without the other letter, but `o,w,l` make three words), but an algorithm is tricky...

Comment: This is actually much worse than maximum coverage; even with a restriction to two-letter words, this is at least as hard as densest subgraph, which is harder than finding a clique.

Comment: Can we offer algorithms with "good" results? (relaxation on "the most efficient"...)

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov Yep I would be grateful for that too! I am sure once ppl start seeing some solution, there will be optimizations which might give us a more efficient solution :)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Could you explain your example?

Comment: @ColonelPanic You can take a look at the example in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31524854/1762592

Answer (score 3):

> <sub>EDIT: This was updated for the edited question. See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31524854/1) for details.</sub>

Based on the comments, one has to assume (or at least consider the possibility) that this is in fact an NP-complete problem. So until someone prooves or disprooves the actual complexity of this problem, here is a brute-force solution that should at least compute the right output.

> <sub>EDIT 2.0: As [shapiro.yaacov pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31532702/3182664), it is indeed NP-complete</sub>

It uses some [utility class](https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/utils/math/combinatorics/CombinationIterable.java) to compute all combinations of a certain number of letters from the initial set of all words. As there are `n^k` combinations of `k` letters (given the initial set of `n` letters), this is clearly not "efficient" in the sense of a polynomial-time solution - but it is not yet clear whether such a solution exists at all.

In order to verify the output in view of the point mentioned in the edited question (namely, that letters had to appear in the resulting list as often as they appeared in the word), I used an example input with words where letters are repeated:

```
"BIKE", "BIKER", "TRIKE", "BEER", DEER", "SEED", "FEED"
```

For this input, the program prints

```
0 letters: [], created words: []
1 letters: [B], created words: []
2 letters: [B, B], created words: []
3 letters: [B, B, B], created words: []
4 letters: [B, E, E, R], created words: [BEER]
5 letters: [B, D, E, E, R], created words: [BEER, DEER]
6 letters: [B, D, E, E, F, R], created words: [BEER, DEER, FEED]
7 letters: [B, D, E, E, F, R, S], created words: [BEER, DEER, SEED, FEED]
8 letters: [B, D, E, E, F, I, K, R], created words: [BIKE, BIKER, BEER, DEER, FEED]
```

Maybe it can be considered as being helpful, maybe as a starting point or building block for others.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MaximizeWords
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(
            "BIKE",
            "BIKER",
            "TRIKE",

            "BEER",
            "DEER",
            "SEED",
            "FEED"
        );

        List<Character> allLetters = 
            new ArrayList<Character>(allLettersOf(words));
        for (int n=0; n<=8; n++)
        {
            CombinationIterable<Character> combinations =
                new CombinationIterable<Character>(n, allLetters);

            List<Solution> solutions = new ArrayList<Solution>();
            for (List<Character> combination : combinations)
            {
                Collections.sort(combination);
                Solution solution = new Solution(words, combination);
                solutions.add(solution);
            }
            Solution bestSolution = Collections.max(solutions, 
                new Comparator<Solution>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(Solution s0, Solution s1)
                {
                    return Integer.compare(
                        s0.createdWords.size(), s1.createdWords.size());
                }
            });
            System.out.println(bestSolution);
        }
    }

    static class Solution
    {
        List<Character> letters;
        List<String> createdWords;

        public Solution(List<String> words, List<Character> letters)
        {
            this.letters = letters;
            this.createdWords = computeCreatedWords(words, letters);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return letters.size() + " letters: " + letters
                + ", created words: " + createdWords;
        }
    }

    private static List<String> computeCreatedWords(
        List<String> words, List<Character> letters)
    {
        List<String> createdWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String word : words)
        {
            if (creates(letters, word))
            {
                createdWords.add(word);
            }
        }
        return createdWords;
    }

    private static boolean creates(List<Character> letters, String word)
    {
        List<Character> copy = new ArrayList<Character>(letters);
        for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
        {
            Character c = Character.valueOf(word.charAt(i));
            if (!copy.remove(c))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private static List<Character> lettersOf(String word)
    {
        List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
        {
            letters.add(Character.valueOf(word.charAt(i)));
        }
        return letters;
    }

    private static Set<Character> allLettersOf(Iterable<String> words)
    {
        Set<Character> letters = new TreeSet<Character>();
        for (String word : words)
        {
            letters.addAll(lettersOf(word));
        }
        return letters;
    }
}







//=============================================================================
// These classes are taken from https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics


/**
 * A class providing an iterator over all combinations of a certain number
 * of elements of a given set. For a set S with n = |S|, there are are n^k 
 * combinations of k elements of the set. This is the number of possible
 * samples when doing sampling with replacement. Example:<br />
 * <pre>
 * S = { A,B,C }, n = |S| = 3
 * k = 2 
 * m = n^k = 9
 * 
 * Combinations:
 * [A, A]
 * [A, B]
 * [A, C]
 * [B, A]
 * [B, B]
 * [B, C]
 * [C, A]
 * [C, B]
 * [C, C]
 * </pre>
 *  
 * @param <T> The type of the elements
 */
final class CombinationIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<T>>
{
    /**
     * The input elements
     */
    private final List<T> input;

    /**
     * The sample size
     */
    private final int sampleSize;

    /**
     * The total number of elements that the iterator will provide
     */
    private final int numElements;

    /**
     * Creates an iterable over all multisets of 
     * 'sampleSize' elements of the given array.
     *  
     * @param sampleSize The sample size
     * @param input The input elements
     */
    public CombinationIterable(int sampleSize, List<T> input)
    {
        this.sampleSize = sampleSize;
        this.input = input;
        numElements = (int) Math.pow(input.size(), sampleSize);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<List<T>>()
        {
            /**
             * The element counter
             */
            private int current = 0;

            /**
             * The indices of the elements that are currently chosen
             */
            private final int chosen[] = new int[sampleSize];

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return current < numElements;
            }

            @Override
            public List<T> next()
            {
                if (!hasNext())
                {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("No more elements");
                }

                List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(sampleSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
                {
                    result.add(input.get(chosen[i]));
                }
                increase();
                current++;
                return result;
            }

            /**
             * Increases the k-ary representation of the selection of 
             * elements by one.
             */
            private void increase()
            {
                // The array of 'chosen' elements for a set of size n 
                // effectively is a number represented in k-ary form, 
                // and thus, this method does nothing else than count. 
                // For example, when choosing 2 elements of a set with 
                // n=10, the contents of 'chosen' would represent all
                // values 
                // 00, 01, 02,... 09,
                // 10, 11, 12,... 19,
                // ...
                // 90, 91, 92, ...99
                // with each digit indicating the index of the element
                // of the input array that should be placed at the
                // respective position of the output array.
                int index = chosen.length - 1;
                while (index >= 0)
                {
                    if (chosen[index] < input.size() - 1)
                    {
                        chosen[index]++;
                        return;
                    }
                    chosen[index] = 0;
                    index--;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "May not remove elements from a combination");
            }
        };
    }
}

/**
 * Utility methods used in the combinatorics package
 */
class Utils
{
    /**
     * Utility method for computing the factorial n! of a number n.
     * The factorial of a number n is n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1, or more
     * formally:<br />
     * 0! = 1 <br />
     * 1! = 1 <br />
     * n! = n*(n-1)!<br />
     *
     * @param n The number of which the factorial should be computed
     * @return The factorial, i.e. n!
     */
    public static BigInteger factorial(int n)
    {
        BigInteger f = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            f = f.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        return f;
    }    
    /**
     * A magic utility method that happens to return the number of
     * bits that are set to '1' in the given number.
     *  
     * @param n The number whose bits should be counted
     * @return The number of bits that are '1' in n
     */
    public static int countBits(int n)
    {
        int m = n - ((n >> 1) & 033333333333) - ((n >> 2) & 011111111111);
        return ((m + (m >> 3)) & 030707070707) % 63;
    }

    /**
     * Add all elements from the given iterable into the given collection
     * 
     * @param <T> A type that is related to the elements 
     * @param iterable The iterable
     * @param collection The collection
     */
    public static <T> void addAll(
        Iterable<? extends T> iterable, Collection<? super T> collection)
    {
        for (T t : iterable)
        {
            collection.add(t);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns all elements from the given iterable as a list
     * 
     * @param <T> A type that is related to the elements 
     * @param iterable The iterable
     * @return The list
     */
    public static <T> List<T> asList(Iterable<? extends T> iterable)
    {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        addAll(iterable, list);
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all elements from the given iterable as a set
     * 
     * @param <T> A type that is related to the elements 
     * @param iterable The iterable
     * @return The set
     */
    public static <T> Set<T> asSet(Iterable<? extends T> iterable)
    {
        Set<T> set = new LinkedHashSet<T>();
        addAll(iterable, set);
        return set;
    }

    /**
     * Private constructor to prevent instantiation
     */
    private Utils()
    {

    }
}
```

(Note that, compared to the initial version, there is not much that has changed in the code - basically, instead of using a [ChoiceIterable](https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/utils/math/combinatorics/ChoiceIterable.java) it now uses a [CombinationIterable](https://github.com/javagl/Combinatorics/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/utils/math/combinatorics/CombinationIterable.java). But the number of *combinations* is **much** larger than the number of *choices*, so this is only feasible for much smaller inputs than the initial solution).

Comment: Haven't gone through the code yet, but this is a great start! I just ran the code and one thing I observed was that it used letters multiple times. That would be a constraint in a ideal scenario. You will be able to use a letter only once. If there is a need to have an alphabet mutiple times in a word, then that needs to be treated differently. Will go through the code properly now :) Thanks for this brilliant start!

Comment: OK, this was not clear - I thought about an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_%28formal_languages%29 here. So if I understood correctly: Given a word like `FOO`, one could not use `F,O` as the alphabet, but always needed `F,O,O`, right? Maybe you could edit the question with information like this ...

Comment: Yup I agree, I will add that info!

Comment: Is it necessary to compute words from letters ? Or just calculating the letters from words would be enough ?

Comment: @Marco13 I have made that change to the title and description of the question. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to run the program completely without getting the out of memory exception. Any ideas on how I can run this? Or would this need the help of distributed computing?

Comment: You may try starting it with `java -Xmx1000m MaximizeWords`, or reducing the limit in the `for`-loop from `n<=8` to `n<=7`. There **is** an exponential number of combinations, and until now, neither me nor anybody else made an attempt to reduce this number with some "clever" algorithm. Currently, the program and the approach are rather trivial, and I'm sure there are more tricky approaches (some greedy algorithm, maybe some approximation, or a backtracking with clever pruning).

Answer (score 2):

Finally had some time to look this up and:

This **is** a variation of the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) - it is actually the [maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem). And as I suspected, it is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

So, to conclude, @Marco13 gave an answer that is the best (asymptotically) you can do. It might be optimized, and other tricks, but basically, that's as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

In simple way, you can do the following: I am using C#

```
var output = string.Join("",words.Select(t=>t.ToUpper())).ToCharArray().Distinct();
```

result

```
B,I,K,E,T,R,F,U,L => n=9
```

and if the input will be

```
words = {"Stupid","Stubborn","sun","safe"}, 
then the result would be S,T,U,P,I,D,B,O,R,N,A,F,E and count is 13
```

in other words: your problem is to find the minimal set of letters needed to form the set of words which means remove all repeated characters in the words.

here a working [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zMJCrG)

Comment: The question is not to find distinct characters, but to find a set of size "n" which consists of letters that can be used to make the maximum words from the list of words given to us.

Comment: @VinayGaba in this case you need to deal with a dictionary that contains all possible words and then you can build an algorithm against it otherwise you will not be able to form the word from the set of characters, is this the case? do you have a dictionary?

Comment: U have an array of words that u can see in the description of the question. Treat that as your dictionary.

Comment: @VinayGaba i updated my answer and I provided another set of words and sure, you can't consider the word "born" that can be formed from the set of letter, as outcome because you don't have it in your dictionary "words", am I right? correct me if I am wrong please

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version in Python that uses only ten lines of code for the core algorithm.  It shows all possible combinations of letters for the maximum number of complete words.  It also handles duplicate letters (like `FOO`).

```
import itertools

n = 9
words = ['bike', 'tire', 'fuel', 'biker', 'filter', 'trike']

# preparation: get the union of all letters in all words, including duplicate letters
all_letters = ''
for word in words:
    a = all_letters[:]
    for letter in word:
        if letter in a:
            a = a.replace(letter, '', 1)
        else:
            all_letters += letter

# helper function: find if a word with duplicate letters in a combination
def word_in_combo(word, combo):
    letters = list(combo)
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letters:
            return False
        letters.remove(letter)
    return True

# algorithm: find all words for each combination of n letters
matches = {}
max_matched = 0
for combo in itertools.combinations(all_letters, n):
    matched = 0
    for word in words:
        if word_in_combo(word, combo):
            matched += 1
    matches[combo] = matched
    if matched > max_matched:
        max_matched = matched

# print the best combinations and the matching words
if max_matched == 0:
    print "No combinations for %d letters" % n
else:
    for combo in matches:
        if matches[combo] == max_matched:
            print combo, ':',
            for word in words:
                if word_in_combo(word, combo):
                    print word,
            print
```

For `n=4`, the output is:

```
('e', 'f', 'u', 'l') : fuel
('i', 'e', 't', 'r') : tire
('b', 'i', 'k', 'e') : bike
```

for `n=5`, the output is:

```
('i', 'k', 'e', 't', 'r') : tire trike
('b', 'i', 'k', 'e', 'r') : bike biker
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a version that is written in Python.  The basic algorithm is this: find the most common letter and use it; remove that letter from every word and repeat.  In the process, if we can complete a word with just one letter, use that letter first.

The advantage of this approach is that it "looks ahead" to maximize the number of words as `n` increases.

```
words = ['bike', 'tire', 'fuel', 'biker', 'filter', 'trike']


def next_letter(words):
    """ find the next letter from the most common letter in the words """
    num_words = {}
    max_words = 0
    next = None
    for word in words:
        if len(word) == 1:        # if we can complete this word 
            return word[0]        # with one letter, do it!
        for letter in word:
            n = num_words.get(letter, 0) + 1    # tally the number of words
            num_words[letter] = n               # that use this letter
            if n > max_words:                   # a new maximum?
                max_words = n                   # use it
                next = letter
    return next


output = ''
while words:
    letter = next_letter(words)   # get the next letter
    if not letter: break          # reached the end? exit
    output += letter              # keep track of the letters
    # remove the selected letter from every word and try again
    words = [word.replace(letter, '', 1) if letter in word else word for word in words]

print '{', ','.join(output), '}'
```

The output for this program is here:

> { e,i,r,t,k,b,f,l,u }

Comment: Please see the third comment to the question. In that case your code will give a wrong answer.

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov but according to your other comment (the fifth one), it's good enough.  No need to downvote.

Comment: Please mention it is not the optimal solution - but another one

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov, you just did.  Have you downvoted the other answers for not being optimal either?

Comment: A. I upvoted the other answer since it **does** give an optimal solution - by brute force - as it is written in the answer itself. B. I would like to erase the down vote, but since you have not edited the answer I can't do that. So, as I asked previously, please edit the answer...